# jQuery - highlight table row with .closest() not working

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight targeted row by background color, when anchor is clicked

```
<table>
    <tr> <!-- highlight me! -->
        <td>
            <span id="A-1PP-05">A-1PP-05</span>
        </td>       
    </tr>

    <tr>...</tr>

    <tr>...</tr>    
</table>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
        // target element id
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        // target element
        var $id = $(id);

        // top position relative to the document
        var pos = $id.offset().top;

        // animated top scrolling
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos - 120});
    });
    
    $(':target').closest('tr').css('background', 'yellow');

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This line of code is not working:

```
$(':target').closest('tr').css('background', 'yellow');
```

Clicking on anchor only scrolls down to `<span>` with `id` but doesn't highlight its parent `<tr>` element.

Comment: Your click handler targets `a` links, but your HTML includes no `a` links.

Comment: Shouldn't your `$(':target')` line be inside your click handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `$(':target')` outside the click handler, it runs only once, on page load.  At that time, there is probably no URL fragment at all, so the selector does not match anything, and nothing happens.

If you move that line *inside* the click handler, it will run when the click happens, which is what you want.  However there are still problems.  AFAICT that code runs *before* the actual URL fragment has changed in the browser.  It seems like the timeline is something like:

```
click on anchor ---> event handler runs ---> URL fragment updates
```

You can verify this by testing - if you click a link 2x on the same anchor, the correct `tr` is highlighted on the 2nd click, because at the 2nd click, that fragment is already in the URL.  Or if you click a series of different anchors, the row that is highlighted is always one behind your clicks, because that wass the fragment that was in the URL from the previous click.

So it seems that if you want to use the `$(':target')` selector, you'll need to do some kind of time/async related trick to wait until the anchor is updated.  That seems pretty risky and impractical.

However there is much simpler solution - you already have the `id` of the `tr` you want to highlight, you even have it as a jQuery object, and saved as a variable.  Using an HTML `id` is *the* most efficient way for jQuery to select an element on the page, and you've already done it, so this is really the ideal option.  Simply replacing the `$(':target')` with `$id` works fine.

Note that this code does not work as a snippet here on SO, something to do with the sandbox not updating the actual URL I guess.  But it works fine on JSFiddle - [here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/zn5adm1y/).

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);

    // top position relative to the document
    var pos = $id.offset().top;

    // animated top scrolling
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos - 120});

    // Remove all bg colours so we can see while testing
    $('tr').css('background', 'none');

    // Highlights previously clicked tr/fragment, no good
    $(':target').closest('tr').css('background', 'yellow');

    // Works without problem!
    // $id.closest('tr').css('background', 'yellow');
})(jQuery);
```